# charging a li po battery while using it through piezoelectric crytals

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

My friends and I are working on a project that requires a pretty long battery life. Since we can't fit any battery powerful enough in the project, we had to use a smaller one, but now, we have to charge it through piezoelectric crystals. Is this possible? If yes can anyone send a circuit diagram showing me how?

```
                                                              Regards,
                                                              Yigido
```

Comment: Here you go: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US6252336B1/US06252336-20010626-D00000.png Don't ask me for details, it's the first one that came up in Google and I don't know anything about it. On a more serious note, if you want a better answer you need to ask a better question. What are your requirements? What are the numbers? Also, this isn't a free design service so this question might be regarded as off-topic anyhow.

Comment: Piezoelectric charging is unrealistic for you.

Comment: the numbers are it is 3.7 V 600 mAH li po battery. I will connect 10 piezoelectric generators in parallel. they each create 0.4 V.

Comment: OK, so they create 0.4 volts each. What current, and what duty cycle? How much mechanical force required to produce this? Chris Stratton is right.

Comment: If you connect them in parallel then you still have 0.4v - series would give 4v....

Comment: http://s.aliexpress.com/Vvq6VVZR 

I will be using those
 http://s.aliexpress.com/Vvq6VVZR 
I am connecting them in parallel because apparently, It doesn't create enough current

Comment: @Yigido Those piezo elements are intended to be used to generate sound. They are not suitable for this application.

Comment: If the battery you wish to charge is 3.7 volts, the charging source must be a 4 volts or so to force charge into the battery.  An 0.4 volt charging source CANNOT charge a 3.7 volt battery.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comments, my advice is: Stop. Just stop. You cannot do what you want, and you are so comprehensively ignorant that you cannot understand what you need.

To begin with, the PZTs you linked are clearly intended to be used as power users, rather than power generators. The links you provided give no data to establish 0.4 volts, and no information about current. To use them as generators would require some means of providing a very large force at high (kHz) frequencies.

Even worse, you claim that they must be used in parallel because " apparently, It doesn't create enough current" Let's pretend that you can, in fact, drive them to 0.4 volts. If you connect them in parallel you will get 0.4 volts, rather than the 4 volts or so that you need. The fact that you don't understand this says that you really, really have no idea what you are doing.

So, give up on piezoelectrics. In fact, you have not justified this requirement. Why, exactly, do you think PZTs will do what you want? When you say, "apparently", exactly where did you get this from? Mind you, it's perfectly true that they don't produce enough current to be useful, but that does not mean that the rest of what you right makes any sense.